# Not able to update host json via App Service Editor

Tags: azure-functions, azure-appservice

Is there a way to update host.json of an Azure Function via App Service Editor? On trying the same, I get the following error:

"Failed to save 'host.json'. Error code: 409"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use "AzureFunctionsJobHost__path__to__setting" to add / override host.json settings

```
"AzureFunctionsJobHost__functionTimeout": "05:00:00"
```

Info found here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#override-hostjson-values 
 
Btw, I think you can use "-1" if you don't want timeout at all and your tier/plan supports this.